# File not found exception in react native

Tags: android, react-native, filenotfoundexception

I am making a music player with react native. Some songs causes error because they have %20 in their filenames. For example My%20music%20.mp3. I logged the filepath and it gave me something like file:///storage/emulated/0/xender/audio/My%20music%20.mp3. But when i try to play the music, it gives me an exception.
The exception is h.f.c.d.t0.t$a: java.io.FileNotFoundException: storage/emulated/0/xender/audio/My music .mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).
See!! The file path now has space instead of %20, and it is making it not to find the file. How can i fix that?
I'm using React native expo-AV to play the music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%20` is the HTML encoded value for space. When you get the file path, replacing the `%20` with a **space** might work.

```
var str = "HELLO%20WORLD";
alert(decodeURI(str))
```

Comment: it worked thanks. but instead of decoding, i wanted to encode. I wanted to change from space to %20, so i used the encode keyword. Thank you